# 'X' as an array of at least two dimensions

Tags: r, arrays, rstudio

Very new to R and RStudio and the whole concept of coding language. I'm trying to create reproducible code so I can properly ask a question.

The first error says:

> Error in colSums(cTrain * log(pTrain) + cCar * log(pCar) + cSM * log(pSM)) :
>   'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Using this code, where can I fix this so that 'x' can have two dimensions?

```
mydata <- structure(list(LUGGAGE=c(0,1,0,1,0), GA=c(0,0,0,0,0), TRAIN_AV=c(1,1,1,1,1), CAR_AV=c(1,1,1,1,1), SM_AV=c(1,1,1,1,1), 
               TRAIN_TT=c(114,142,235,193,227), TRAIN_CO=c(40,109,124,90,94),
               SM_TxT=c(44,91,179,119,108), SM_CO=c(46,132,132,127,118),
               CAR_TT=c(140,110,170,150,286), CAR_CO=c(123,104,80,95,169), CHOICE=c(2,2,3,3,2)),
               .Names=c("Luggage","GA","TRAIN_AV","CAR_AV","SM_AV","TRAIN_TT","TRAIN_CO","SM_TT","SM_CO","CAR_TT","CAR_CO","CHOICE"), 
               row.names=c(NA,5L), class="data.frame")

## Initial value of parameters
initPar <- 8


### Log-Likelihood Function of the Logit Model
library("maxLik")
loglik <- function(x) {
  ## Parameters
  # Alternative Specific Constants
  asc_train   <- x[1]
  asc_sm      <- x[2]
  # Travel Time to Destination
  ttime       <- x[3]
  # Travel Cost to Destination
  tcost_train <- x[4]
  tcost_car   <- x[5]
  tcost_sm    <- x[6]
  # Effect of Swiss Annual Season Ticket
  ga <- x[7]
  # Effect of luggage
  luggage <- x[8]

  ## Log-Likelihood Variable
  LL = 0

  ## Utility Function Vin
  train  <- asc_train*matrix(1, nrow=nrow(mydata), ncol = 1) + tcost_train*mydata$TRAIN_CO + ttime*mydata$TRAIN_TT/100 + ga*mydata$GA + luggage*mydata$LUGGAGE
  car    <-                                                    tcost_car*mydata$CAR_CO     + ttime*mydata$CAR_TT/100                  + luggage*mydata$LUGGAGE
  sm     <- asc_sm*matrix(1, nrow=nrow(mydata), ncol = 1)    + tcost_sm*mydata$SM_CO       + ttime*mydata$SM_TT/100    + ga*mydata$GA + luggage*mydata$LUGGAGE

  ## exp(Vin) and Control for Mode Availability
  train  <- mydata$TRAIN_AV *exp(train)
  car    <- mydata$CAR_AV   *exp(car)
  sm     <- mydata$SM_AV    *exp(sm)

  ## Choice Probabilities
  deno   <- (train + car + sm)

  ## Individual Choice Probabilities
  pTrain <- mydata$TRAIN_AV *(train / deno)
  pCar   <- mydata$CAR_AV   *(car   / deno)
  pSM    <- mydata$SM_AV    *(sm    / deno)

  pTrain <- (pTrain!=0) *pTrain + (pTrain==0)
  pCar   <- (pCar!=0)   *pCar   + (pCar==0)
  pSM    <- (pSM!=0)    *pSM    + (pSM==0)

  ## Choice Results
  cTrain <- mydata$CHOICE == "1"
  cCar   <- mydata$CHOICE == "3"
  cSM    <- mydata$CHOICE == "2"

  ## Log-Likelihood Function
  LL <- colSums(cTrain*log(pTrain) + cCar*log(pCar) + cSM*log(pSM))
}


### Maximization of Log-Likelihood Function ###
# Parameter Optimization
result <- maxLik(loglik, start=numeric(initPar))

# Parameter Estimation, Hessian Matrix Calculation
parameters    <- result$estimate
hessianMatrix <- result$hessian

# T-Statistic Calculation
tval <- parameters/sqrt(-diag(solve(hessianMatrix)))

# L(0), Log-Likelihood When All parameters = 0
L0 <- loglik(numeric(initPar))
# LL, Maximumum Likelihood
LL <- result$maximum
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicely asked question with a reproducible example; upvoted!

Your problem was very simple. Your function looks for a variable called `mydata$LUGGAGE` that doesn't exist. R is case sensitive and your column is called `mydata$Luggage`.

All you have to do is

```r
names(mydata)[1] <- "LUGGAGE"
```

Now run your script and you should get this result:

```r
result <- maxLik(loglik, start=numeric(initPar))
result
# Maximum Likelihood estimation
# Newton-Raphson maximisation, 30 iterations
# Return code 2: successive function values within tolerance limit
# Log-Likelihood: -1.744552e-07 (8 free parameter(s))
# Estimate(s): -277.7676 -250.6531 8.651811 -1.680196 -4.208955 -1.281697 0 354.4692
```

Comment: Right. Case sensitive, thanks @Allan!

I edited the spelling error and reran the code. Next error I got was:

**Error in solve.default(hessianMatrix) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[7,7] = 0**

I still managed to get the same results as you though!

Comment: I don't think that's a problem with your code as such. That error tells you that R's linear algebra pack can't solve your hessianMatrix. That's because its determinant is zero, which means it can't be inverted, which is required to solve it.  If you look at the hessianMatrix, both row 7 and column 7 are all zeros